# JQuery: Event handlers stop working when window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/4QLDC/6

This is my JS code:

```
var toggleContent = function (event) {
    $(event.target).siblings().toggle();
};
var showOrHidePanels = function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth < 980) {
        $(".headBar1").siblings().hide();
        $(".headBar1").parent().css("min-height", 0);
        $(".headBar1").css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(".headBar1").on("click", toggleContent);
    }
    else {
        $(".headBar1").siblings().show();
        $(".headBar1").parent().removeAttr("style");
        $(".headBar1").css("cursor", "auto");
        $(".headBar1").off("click", toggleContent);
    }
};
$(function () {
    showOrHidePanels();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    showOrHidePanels();
});
```

This is what I am trying to achieve.

When the window width is less than 300px:

1. The content box should collapse
2. The headings should become links
3. When a heading is clicked, its content box should toggle

The first two are happening, but the third one is what I am having trouble with. Some of the time it works and some of the time it doesn't (the behaviour is unpredictable; in the JSFiddle page if you try resizing the "Result" frame 6-7 times, it will work fine the first six times but fail the seventh time). What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: have you tried `media-query`..??

Comment: You can make all the changes with CSS, so you have two options: 1) use `media-query`s to detect browser width, or 2) use jQuery to detect the width, and add/remove a class from `body` or a `#container`.

Comment: @Mooseman The issue is not with the part where I find the screen size. I believe that the event on/off code is not working properly.

Comment: @AjithNair I added an answer that is working here. Let me know if it's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var toggleContent = function (event) {
    $(event.target).siblings().toggle();
};
var showOrHidePanels = function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $(".headBar1").off("click");
    if (windowWidth < 300) {
        $(".headBar1").siblings().hide();
        $(".headBar1").parent().css("min-height", 0);
        $(".headBar1").css("cursor", "pointer");        
        $(".headBar1").on("click", toggleContent);
    }
    else {        
        $(".headBar1").siblings().show();
        $(".headBar1").parent().removeAttr("style");
        $(".headBar1").css("cursor", "auto");       
    }
};
$(function () {
    showOrHidePanels();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    showOrHidePanels();
});
```

Is that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that's more fitting in this new era of awesome browser would be to use `@media (max-width: 300px)`. All modern browser can use this, and it simply applies specific css rules.

```
/* Define css rules for when the windows is wider than 300px */

@media (max-width: 300px) {
    /* Set parent's min height and such */
    /* display: none and display: block relevant content */

    .headBar {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

I personally use this approach to make the site viewable through mobile phones and smaller windows, and it works perfectly once you get a hang of it.

Most changes you do are relevant to css anyways. All you need to do is have a good structure of classes and such, which you should have regardless.

Comment: I was not familiar with media queries. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4QLDC/8/

```
function toggleContent(ths) {
    console.log('toggle!');
    $(ths).siblings().toggle();
};
var showOrHidePanels = function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth < 300) {
        console.log('Under: ' + windowWidth)
        $(".headBar1").siblings().hide();
        $(".headBar1").parent().css("min-height", 0);
        $(".headBar1").css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(".headBar1").on("click.toggle", function(){ toggleContent(this); });
    } else {
        console.log('Over: ' + windowWidth)
        $(".headBar1").siblings().show();
        $(".headBar1").parent().removeAttr("style");
        $(".headBar1").css("cursor", "auto");
        $(".headBar1").off("click.toggle");
    }
};
$(function () {
    showOrHidePanels();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    showOrHidePanels();
});
```

---

I want beyond and moved styles all into the CSS so that only one class has to be added and removed, and not multiple CSS properties. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4QLDC/12/

CSS:

```
.botContentBox {
    min-height: 200px;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0
}
.headBar1 {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #880000;
    border:5px solid #fff;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:17px;
    line-height:17px;
    padding:10px 10px;
    width:auto;
    margin:0 0 5px 0
}
.botContentBox.lt300{
    min-height: 0px;
}
.botContentBox.lt300 .headBar1{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.botContentBox.lt300 .botContentHolder{
    display: none
}
```

JS:

```
var showOrHidePanels = function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth < 300) {
        console.log('Under: ' + windowWidth)
        $(".headBar1").parent().addClass('lt300');
        $(".headBar1").on("click.toggle", function(){ $(this).siblings().toggle(); });
    } else {
        console.log('Over: ' + windowWidth)
        $(".headBar1").siblings().show(); // in case it was toggled on/off
        $(".headBar1").parent().removeClass('lt300');
        $(".headBar1").off("click.toggle");
    }
};
$(function () {
    showOrHidePanels();
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    showOrHidePanels();
});
```

Comment: I love css class solutions, but it would be even nicer if we knew the parent elements so it would get the class toggled instead. That way we could probably do only `$('#parent_name').toggleClass('lt300', $(window).width() < 300)` instead of the entire function :)

Comment: @RobinCastlin I moved the single line of the `toggleContent` function to the anonymous function. Since we still need to bind/unbind the toggle function, that's not really an option.

Comment: Sure it is, if you'd toggle visibility between a clickable and unclickable element with the same content. Might even make more sense if you use `<a>` for the clickable one.